Difference between Double Descent phenomenon and Benign overfitting
I am trying to wrap my head around understanding the difference between Double descent phenomenon and Benign overfitting.
Double descent occurs in a model when the test error rises as the model complexity increases after a certain point and then again reduces in the highly overparametrized regime.
I have not yet found any exact definition of benign overfitting, however it also deals with generalization in overparametrized regime.
On the surface they seem same, however I am not exactly sure. Can someone please explain the similarity and difference between them ?
